# .show .hide functions not working error in code maybe

Tags: jquery, click, hide, show

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#light").hide();  
    $('.createmessage').click(function() {  
        $('#light').show();    
    });
    $('#fade').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
    });
    $('.cancelButton').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
    });
});
```

​
That is the jQuery I am working on and I'm pretty sure something is majorly wrong. 1 it does not seem to look right and two the codes not working.

the jsfiddle link here
http://jsfiddle.net/6aNL5/

If someone could explain what I am doing wrong, please by all means. I like to learn and this is just practice for me I suppose.

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery in a script block with inline `onclick` and other event attributes? When the "button" is clicked to show the dialog you show the `#fade` element via the inline `onclick` but you have no code to hide it again. (As an aside, why are you using a span element as a pseudo-button? That is an accessibility fail for users who can't or don't use a mouse or other pointing device.)

Comment: You think I care about users who don't use a mouse. Lol! 

NOPE.

I was fixing the original html from a site from way back, and took out the inlines, never realizing I missed one.

Comment: Assuming you are not joking, you need to start caring about non-mouse users. It's no more trouble to make your site work for them too if you just use the right element(s) for the job.

Comment: How is using a span going to effect users without a mouse? clearly you can tell its a button. I styled it the way it is for its purposes. Thanks

Comment: With the keyboard you can tab between any elements that can receive focus, which includes anchors, buttons and form elements. Once said elements have focus you can activate them by pressing Enter or the space bar - which will trigger the click event the same as a mouse click would've, without any extra coding effort to make it work. But you can't tab to a span so there's no way to "click" it via keyboard. In your case if you used an anchor element instead you could still style it the way you want but it would work for mouse _and_ keyboard users.

Comment: Oh. well with this feature, it does not matter to me. I now understand what you mean. Thank you for clarifying that up for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsfiddle is set to use Mootools, so that's probably why nothing's working on there. Besides that, I think the problem here is code sloppiness. You shouldn't need to attach event listeners inline with your HTML. So for example, instead of:

```
<span class="createMessage" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">
```

Do this in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#light").hide();  
    $('.createMessage').click(function() { // This was misspelt before
        $('#light').show(); 
        $('#fade').show();
    });
    $('#fade').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
    });
    $('.cancelButton').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
        $('#fade').hide();
    });
});
```

`.show()` and `.fade()` simply toggle the `display` property anyways. And now, you're separating your HTML structure from your interactive JavaScript which makes debugging way easier.

Comment: Yeah thats why I started creating the jsfiddle. The inline event listeners were messing my entire website up! So I was like hey, lets make this a jQuery file, seperately. After Reviewing the jsfiddle I did see mootools :/ oops thanks for pointing that one out! 

And I never saw the misspelling thank you. I like how to described to me what I did wrong. Great lesson in my eyes.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the button so when it is clicked the dialog comes up as before but now cancel goes back to the original view of the page. Here is the jsfiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/6aNL5/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("#light").hide();  
    $('.createmessage').click(function() {  
        $('#light').show();    
    })
    $('#fade').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
    });
    $('.cancelButton').click(function() {
        $('#light').hide();
        $('#fade').hide();
    });
});
```

This makes it work as far as I can tell (at least on the paths we can try on jsfiddle). Does it look like it is supposed to?    ​

Comment: Ok can I ask what really is different? I did almost exactly the same besides the double hides.?

Comment: The last line of code (3rd line from the bottom): `$('#fade').hide();`. The cancel click now hides both `#light` and `#fade` divs.

Comment: Need to add the same line to the `#fade` click handler, too.

Comment: Or remove the `#fade` click handler -- it isn't clear if it is even needed. If it isn't clear, I stick with don't make the change and just show one thing at a time until it is clear what should happen. I'm operating under the assumption this is a learning exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The html code in the jsfiddle was making it so we had to add two .hide or two .show. so instead I wrapped them in a div. like so

```
<span class="createMessage">
    <span>Create Message</span>
</span>
<div id="messagePop" class="messagePopper">
    <div id="light" class="white_content">
        <div class="topborder"><span>NewMessage</span></div>
        <div class="formbody">
            <form id="privatemessage" action="/privmsg" method="post" name="post" class="newmessage">
                <input placeholder="Message To:" name="username[]" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Message To:'){this.value = '';}" type="text" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Message To:';}" class="usernameinput">
                <input required placeholder="Subject:" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode==13){return false}" maxlength="64" name="subject" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Subject:'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Subject:';}" type="text" class="usernameinput"/>
                <textarea class="noThis" name="message"  onfocus="if(this.value == 'Type your message here'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Type your message here';}" >Type your message here</textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="bottombuttons">
            <span class="button"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="post" class="submitbutton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">
            </form> 
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<button class="submitbutton cancelButton uiButton uiButtonConfirm uiButtonLarge">Cancel</button></span>
        </div> 
    </div>          
    <div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
      $("#messagePop").hide();  
      $('.createMessage').click(function() {  
          $('#messagePop').show();    
      });
      $('#fade').click(function() {
          $('#messagePop').hide();
      });
      $('.cancelButton').click(function() {
          $('#messagePop').hide();
      });
});
```

​
After the help from everyone I realized what a dope I was, correcting myself. And wanted to show it to you all.

http://jsfiddle.net/6aNL5/3/